# How to write c# expression in workflow designer instead of vb

Tags: c#, workflow, workflow-foundation

I want to use workflow foundation as a service for my asp.net web application , i download a sample code but in the designer i cant write in c# , is there any solution for that?

sample code:
https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/forums/how-to-integrate-asp-net-web-application-with-wwf

[screen shot of workflow designer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EUt8B.png)

Comment: I'm a bit confused by the question, but the page you linked has a link to an article, and that article has all code as both vb and c#. You just need to click on the tabs for visual basic or c# in the code snippets.

Comment: i didn't mean the code behind , there is a designer for workflow that allow to write in vb only , and i cant change that.

Comment: @OdayM.Saed **DON'T** use Workflow Foundation in the first place. It's been abandoned. [WF 4.5 added C# expressions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/windows-workflow-foundation/csharp-expressions) back in 2012 but well, WF was eventually abandoned. There are no plans to port it to .NET Core, Powershell's Workflow feature that depended on it was *also* abandoned.

Comment: If you insist on using WF, use WF 4.5.

Comment: Check the Github issue [Port Workflow Foundation to .NET Core](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/issues/2394). It was closed and one of the main obstacles was the dependence on the System.XAML library. *Maybe* this will change once .NET Core 3.0 comes out. Near the end of the discussion people start mentioning alternatives like [an unofficial port project](https://github.com/dmetzgar/corewf) and [an alternative implementation](https://github.com/danielgerlag/workflow-core)